# Мета-сайт сообщества Русский язык

Tags: обсуждение

Мета – место, где собирается сообщество, чтобы обсудить важнейшие вопросы своей самоорганизации, место, где каждый может быть услышанным. Сплоченное сообщество, имеющее конечную цель, начинается именно с Меты. На Мете каждый специалист, ставящий перед собой задачу построения базы знаний в своей области, может рассказать свое видение будущего сайта и вместе с коллегами определить настоящее.

#### В каких случаях стоит просить участников воспользоваться Метой?

- В случае обсуждения правил либо споров о них в комментариях на основном сайте. Вместо открытой дискуссии под вопросами и ответами на основном сайте просто попросите другого участника (или сделайте сами) задать вопрос на Мете. Вопрос должен содержать лишь описание спорного момента, а все мысли каждой из сторон должны быть разнесены по ответам так, чтобы сообщество могло голосовать.
- В случае, если вы видите, что другой участник не до конца понимает правила сообщества, но не можете найти подходящий раздел справки или FAQ–вопрос, попросите участника задать вопрос на Мете и ответьте ему (либо опубликуйте вопрос с ответом). В будущем данный вопрос станет FAQ–вопросом, на который можно будет ссылаться в случае непонимания правил новыми участниками сообщества.
- В случае необходимости (желания) обсудить важный аспект самоорганизации сообщества, провести публичное обсуждение или голосование по какому–либо вопросу.

#### Какие публикации на Мете будут полезны сообществу?

1. **Вопросы о миссии проекта**. Мета является двухсторонним каналом взаимодействия участников конкретного сообщества и компании, поддерживающей и развивающей инфраструктуру сети Stack Exchange, где любой участник сообщества может дать отзыв о работе сайта и желаемых улучшения, а компания, в свою очередь, через [управляющего сообществом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/) или наиболее увлеченных участников рассказывает о конечной миссии проекта.
2. **Вопросы о сообществе**. Никто, кроме самих участников, не может знать, что необходимо для сообщества, чтобы быть успешными. Если вы видите способ, как улучшить сайт, пожалуйста, расскажите о нем коллегам. Определите, кто когда и как поможет вам сделать Интернет лучшим местом для получения ответа по вашей специальности. Создайте свой [островок знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146/)! Уверен, многие коллеги вас поддержат!
3. **Вопросы о правилах сайта и движке (в том числе FAQ–вопросы)**. Модель вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange [сильно отличается](/tour) от стандартной модели форумов. Важнейшей задачей «старичков» сообщества является обучение новых участников правилам, принятым в сообществе. Для этого необходимо правила описать в общедоступном месте и создать обучающие материалы (FAQ–вопросы).

#### Дополнительно

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на страницу справочного центра «[Что такое Мета и как она работает?](/help/whats-meta)»

---

Подводя итог, как мне кажется, построение здорового самодостаточного сообщества начинается с Меты. Исторически сложилось, что сообщество Русский язык долгое время существовало без своей Меты, как результат, участники не успели сформировать институт «Мета–обсуждений». Спешу предложить это исправить!

Пожалуйста, опубликуйте в ответах к этому вопросу ваши идеи, что бы вы хотели сделать в самое ближайшее время для обучения других участников использовать Мету с целью накопления знаний о сайте и сообществе.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день! **Меня интересует вопрос о постановке знака "минус" в качестве оценки ответа.** Возможно, это нужный инструмент, но им обычно мало кто пользуется. Знак "минус"  ставится в том случае, когда отвечающий (обычно из новых) совсем "не в теме", на такой ответ надо как-то реагировать.

**Но в настоящий момент "минусовка" используется для сведения счетов с теми, кто тебе неугоден. Иногда в ответ он также получает "минус". Разве это нормальная ситуация?**

Пример от 05.06.17 г. [Нужна ли запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, стоящими рядом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432403/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-2/432404#432404)

Обсуждается вопрос, который в текстах Нацкорпуса решается по-разному, так как регулирующее правило Розенталя (о смысловом единстве однородных членов) допускает авторскую трактовку. Я ссылаюсь на правило,  привожу решение, привожу примеры из Нацкорпуса,  но участник Мимоходов ставит мне минус.  Почему? Да потому что в этот день Мимоходову очень не понравился мой (принятый автором) ответ на вопрос [С какой буквы "вселенная"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432396/%D0%A1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F/432399#432399), за который я также получила минус. Такой же минус получает Серж за свое мнение, который  в чем-то возразил Мимоходову и тем самым вызвал его недовольство.

**У нас опять начинается война, нормально работать не будем? Я прошу общество разобраться с этим явлением и дать справедливую оценку моим ответам.** Я не утверждаю их абсолютную правильность, но они не заслуживают минусовой метки, которая обозначает "ответ не является полезным".

В связи с вышеизложенным, **предлагаю обсудить статус знака "минус"**.

К примеру, знак "плюс" обозначает согласие с ответом (здесь  всё ясно), а что обозначает знак "минус"? Да всё, что угодно, ведь пояснений к нему нет: а) ответ абсолютно неверен, противоречит правилам; б) мне не нравится это ответ (не знаю почему, но не нравится); в) мне не нравится отвечающий, я ему всегда ставил (или буду теперь ставить) "минус".

**Как сделать этот знак объективным и полезным?**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ТЕМЕ

Получаю очередной минус за вопрос rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432382/…. При этом **я отвечаю точно по теме вопроса о конкретной фразе**  "Или Александр обыграл «чаша медленная кофе или чая?», то есть хотя бы делаю предположения, а Мимоходов говорит: "По поводу "кофе или чая" — не понял, что вы имели в виду". И это он считает правильным ответом. **Стихотворения Пушкина он не читал, думал, что Баратынский, по поводу Дидро его сомнения одолевают, тут ему вообще нечего сказать, но это, с его точки зрения, хороший ответ**. У нас форум по русскому языку, а не по литературе, и автора вопроса интересовала **грамматика конкретной фразы**, поэтому я  разбирала именно её. Но мой ответ опять обозначен как ненужный. Так что "травля" началась и продолжается. Придется просить помощи у руководства форума

Comment: Будьте добры, задайте отдельный вопрос: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Comment: @Sharon, а здесь минусы ставят,исходя из субъективных убеждений, предпочтений.

Comment: Это да, но всё-таки сейчас этим знаком не злоупотребляют и даже могут добавить объяснение. Здесь же рассмотрена несколько другая ситуация, которая сейчас уже скорее в прошлом.